# Using a getchar() while loop; but, results are kinda strange

Tags: c

I'm working my way through "The C Programming Language" (K&R), and did one of the exercises. The exercise was to print the number of spaces, tabs and newlines until EOF. Great, that works. But, I started getting clever and added the printf()'s you see below that actually say, "Space" or "Tab" or "newline". It *should* print that as I type, but, it the while loop only seems to run once I hit enter.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int c, nb, nt, nl;

    nb = nt = nl = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            nb += 1;
            printf("Space\n");
        }
        if (c == '\t') {
            nt += 1;
            printf("Tab\n");
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            nl += 1;
            printf("New Line\n");
        }

    }

    printf("%d spaces, %d tabs, %d newlines",nb,nt,nl);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
a b
Space
New Line
c d e
Space
Space
New Line
f   g
Tab
New Line
3 spaces, 1 tabs, 3 newlines
```

What I expected to see was something more like this:

```
a Spaceb
New Line
c Spaced Spacee
New Line
f   tabg
New Line
3 spaces, 1 tabs, 3 newlines
```

So, why do I get what I get, and not what I expect?

And, yes, if I was really caring, I'd make the words 'space[s]' 'tab[s]' and 'newline[s]' plural vs. not based on the value, but, it's just an exercise. ;)

Comment: `stdin` is usually line-buffered, so the terminal doesn't send the input to your programme before a newline is entered.

Comment: Thanks.. I thought that might be happening... But, how do I make stdin not be line-buffered? So I can process keystrokes in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal is in canonical mode - characters are accumulated until end of line. Only then are they send to user (one by one).

If you want immediate response, you have to switch the terminal to raw mode.

PS. More or less, like this:

```
struct termios t;

tcgetattr (0, &t);

t.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
t.c_cc [VMIN] = 1;
t.c_cc [VTIME] = 0;

tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, &t);
```

Comment: Had to add: #include <termios.h>  But, otherwise, worked as expected. Thanks!